# I'm trying to configure traefik + docker, but the browser loads the https url forever, do you know why?

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm trying to configure traefik + docker but I'm having troubles: the browser loads the URL forever.
This is my actual configuration:

**traefik.toml**

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

# https is the default
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "cloud.castignoli.it"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "marco.castignoli@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Then I have the **acme.json**, actually filled by treafik with the correct values.

I'm trying to activate https for the container *foo*, the domain is hello.cloud.castignoli.it
**foo** has only this label

```
traefik.frontend.rule=Host:hello.cloud.castignoli.it
```

These are traefik's logs

```
time="2018-10-11T08:04:50Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"reverse-proxy.traefik.\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:reverse-proxy.traefik.\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [reverse-proxy.traefik.]: acme: Error 400 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed - Error creating new order :: DNS name ends in a period"
```

This is the traefik dashboard
[traefik's dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5dtg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the domain for the traefik that is trying to generate a certificate for a non-existent domain.

In `docker-compose.yml` set `labels` with your domain or do not use `--api`. For example:

```
  image: traefik                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  command: --api --docker                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    - "80:80"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    - "443:443"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    - "8080:8080"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  networks:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    - web                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  labels:                                                                                                                                       
    - "traefik.docker.network=web"                                                                                                                                      
    - "traefik.port=8081"                                                                    
    - "traefik.enable=true"                                                                                                                                       
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:your-awesome-host.com"
```